# Using timeouts to automatically detect blind sql injection exploits

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection, vulnerability-scanners, dvwa, black-box

I'm working on a penetration testing tool, and I have error-based sql injection pretty much covered, but I was wondering, is it possible to use timeouts, along with built in sql commands to detect an issue? In the application DVWA, I attempted the query

```
' OR 1=1; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';#
```

in the sql injection box, and it gave me a generic syntax error. I then attempted

```
'; sleep(5000); #
```

and that also failed with a similar error. These were the only two sleep methods I found, so how in the world is this attack executed, and would it be a reliable method to say, wait for 20 seconds, and have a timeout of 15?

Comment: Considering we don't have the actual PHP code, there is almost no way to tell if it's even remotely exploitable.

Comment: You could have a look how SQL-map does this detection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know that a SQL exploit worked, you need to be sure that some code you supplied is indeed being executed server side.

One instance of SQL injection could be a query built as

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{user}' AND password='{pass}';
```

By replacing, say, `user=squeamish&pass=ossifrage` with `user=admin&pass=' OR ''='`, you make it so that the query executed is

```
... WHERE username='admin' AND password='' OR ''='';
```

which has good chances of getting administrator login. This is **one** query.

If you replace, as you did, with `' OR 1=1; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';#`, (actually I believe that # ought to have been --, but maybe both character sequences are valid comment initiators? I forget), you get

```
... WHERE username='' OR 1=1; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';# other code ignored
```

and these are **two queries**. Much more powerful syntax, yes, since you can now execute *any query at all* as your second one. But several engines do not, or can be configured not to, execute anything beyond the first query. You would then not get any delay, and thus **mistakenly** conclude that the exploit did not work.

Your second attempt also makes use of the "two query" method.

In order to get a significant delay, you need a *function* which will take a long time to execute. Depending on the engine, you might do well with:

```
' OR SLEEP(5)='
```

This will yield a query of

```
... WHERE username='admin' AND password='' OR SLEEP(5)='' ...
```

which, to be evaluated, requires that the engine return the result of a sleep(). The query will most likely fail, but before it does, it will wait five seconds. That's how you can *automatically* know that a crafted query string would yield better results.

For example in MySQL you get

```
mysql> select 5=SLEEP(5);
+------------+
| 5=SLEEP(5) |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (5.00 sec) <----
```